# CMAKE way to search for .exe file in the CLists text?

Tags: cmake, clion, cl

Say I have

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER={$myCompilersEnvVariableName}
```

and it's not configured

is there an if statement that I can place here something like

```
if CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER FALSE
search for cl.exe
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER path/to/cl.exe

break
```

It is not a problem but a theoretical question

Comment: In CMake there is [find_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) which could be used for search executables. Result of this command is stored in the cache variable, and if the variable is already set then it is not rewritten.

Comment: Especially for the MSVC compiler I wouldn't recommend doing this; there are many variables that help you to specify the correct compiler to use other than implementing the search manually. If you do so though, I recommend doing so in a toolchain file; otherwise this makes reusing your project hard...